# jQuery UI dialog added content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way to add content in between two buttons for a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) dialog box? With the code below, I would like to have `OR` written in between the two buttons. Is this possible?

```
$("#dialog-delivery").dialog({
              bgiframe: true,
              resizable: true,
              height:350,
              width:400,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                  "Continue": function() {
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                        $(".option-separate").hide();
                        $("#nonsubscribers").hide();
                        $('<div class="radio-alert">Thank you for your selection</div>').appendTo('#subscribers');
                        $("#change-subs").css('visibility','visible');
                    },
                    "Change to Non-Subscriber": function() {
                          $(this).dialog( "close" );
                          $("#subscribers").hide();
                          $(".option-separate").hide();
                          $("#nonsubscribers").show();
                          $("#change-nonsubs").css('visibility','visible');
                      }
              }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

[It's a little hack-y, but have a look at this demo ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/XqRXJ/)

The relevant addition is a dialog open handler:

```
open: function() {
    $('.ui-button-text:contains("Continue")')
        .parent()
        .after('<div class="button-divider">OR</div>');
}
```

What this does: Select a ui button with some specific text, and insert a `<div>` after it.  The class is important because you will need at least one CSS style in order for the seperator to be placed correctly.  Here are the styles I used:

```
.button-divider {
    margin: .5em .2em .5em 0;
    float: right;
    padding: .2em 0 .3em 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

The important part is `float:right;`, because the ui buttons float, so your separator must also float, in order to be placed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. This is also quite useful for appending text beneath the buttonset.